# Fit of two different functions with boarder as fit parameter

Tags: python, curve-fitting

I have a question about a simple fit function in Python.
I am trying to fit two different functions on a data set and the border between the two regimes should be also a fit parameter.
Very naively I was trying something like this:

```
def FitFunc(x, a, b, c, d, e, border):
    if x < border:
        return a * x + b
    if x > border:
        return c * x**2 + d * x + e
```

But I got a ValueError:

> The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty(), a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

I understand that you can not compare my x array to an integer value (which is not even assigned to a fixed value, this should be done by the curve_fit procedure).

I was not able to find a solution for this supposedly simple problem. Can someone help me out of this?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I constructed an example:
[image: Constructed example]
For the data with x<5 this is perfectly described by a linear function (y=x-3), For x>5 this is perfectly described by a square function (y=x**2/5-3*x/5). Assume you don't know that x is the perfect 'border', is there a way to let curve_fit find out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is saying that comparing the values of an array (`x`) with a scalar value (`border`) is ambiguous.  Do you mean if *any* values of `x` are less than `border` or if *all* values of `x` are less than `border`?

I suspect that what you really want is numpy's `where` function, which is sort of like looping over `x` and deciding which expression to use point-by-point, only much faster:

```
def FitFunc(x, a, b, c, d, e, border):
    out = a * x + b
    out[np.where(x > border)] = c * x**2 + d * x + e
    return out
```

I think that is what you want, and it should work to select the proper functional form based on `border`.

However, I would caution that it may not *do* what you want.  That is, it looks like you intend `border` to be a fitting variable.

Fitting variables in scipy `optimize` routines (and most "curve fitting" contexts) need to be *continuous floating point variables*. Your `border` variable would be used as a discrete, integer value for the index of `x` to change functional form.  The fitting algorithm will first choose a value (let's say 5.0), then make a very small change in that value (to, say, 5.0000002).  That will not change where the breakpoint between your two functional forms is, and the fit will decide that `border` does not change the fit.  I wish I knew a way around this.

Comment: I meant border like the point where one regime ends and the other begins. I am sorry if this led to confusion. I edited it in the original question.

Comment: OK, I altered the answer to match the edited question.